# Laravel 5 fetching related data using 3 models

Tags: laravel, eloquent

hello guys I have this set of database

```
clients(#id,raison_sociale,adresse,)<br>
delivery(#id,client_id(fk),date_del) <br>
details(delivery_id(fk),product_id(fk),qt)
product(id,code,desig,price)
```

and here are my eloquent relationships

```
class Client extends Model {
   public function livraison (){
       return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Livraison');  } }
```

```
 class Detail extends Model
         {
  public function delivery (){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Delivery');}}
```

```
   class Livraison extends Model{
   public function client (){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Client');
     }
public function detail (){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\detail'); }}
```

1. Do I have something wrong with these relationships ?
2. I have a page where I show all of my delivery but I can't find the correct way to fetch this row:
   `raison_soc(from client) & date_del(from delivery)`; and details table (for each client of course )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use App\Models\Client;

Client::with('delivery.detail')->get();
```

I can't test your relationships but assuming you are following the naming conventions your relations should be fine. The above will grab all details that are associated to the delivery by the client.

You could improve your relationship with a hasManyThrough method [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

You would do something like this in your Client class:

```
public function details(){
  return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models`Details', 'App\Models\Livarasion');
}
```

If you explain your 2nd point more clearly I can help you adjust this. Please let me know if you have any issues

Comment: Thank you excojish but it only returned the client information 
what i can't to accomplish is to show the deliveries and the ones who ordered them and the details about them i hope im clearer now

Comment: i did a DD to the results i got a collection about the client info and there is also a relations array about delivery (i think it worked but the detail weren't included and i don't know how to show them )

Comment: return $this->hasMany('App\Models\detail'); }} Detail is incorrect, right? your class name is Liravision, no? That should fix it :)

Comment: as i said i think it worked thank you so much (i had trouble with eloquent relationships and in y 1st learning project i used db:: for raw queries which created problems with string and stuff so THANK YOU !!!

Comment: You'll get it mate, practice makes perfect! Moving on from raw queries is super good, remember that eloquent uses fluent query builder under the scenes so you can still do Join methods! If you ever need help just ask :)